# url parameter to open google maps infowindow on load?

Tags: google-maps, parameters, infowindow

i have a series of links to specific addresses on google maps. several of these addresses have markers with an infowindow. is there any query parameter i can add to the urls to automatically open this infowindow on load?

currently i'm my hrefs look like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=business name 15 main st., city, state
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding iwloc=A to the query string. The "A" represents the marker letter on the map.

Comment: I am using it for destination ie. https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=431%20W%207TH%20ST,%20LOS%20ANGELES&iwloc=B and it is not working for me. Am I doing anything wrong?